How to insert placeholder record in table with every new record entered?
I'm re-purposing a stock access database template from Microsoft website for project tracking.
Tables in question are Properties, Designer, Contractor and Project. Project has a many-to-one relationship with the three previously mentioned tables. Information is most often acquired when completing an application form. However, being that you might see the same designer or contractor across multiple projects, the application form has a combo box to select already-established records for designer or contractor which supplies values for the related forms on the application form (address/city/state/zip).
However, that means I've lost the function of entering new records without having to use the "edit list with form" option. Really interrupts the flow of entry.
I am hoping to find a way to either retain a placeholder record for the Designer and Contractor tables that can be selected from the application form combo box which will allow you to fill in the fields without overwriting the "placeholder" OR after every new record, insert a placeholder row into aforementioned tables.
I attempted to do a macro on one of the tables for "after insert" to "create new record" and it populated multiple rows at one time so I clearly must be misusing or misunderstanding it. I also tried searching it, but am not having luck. Which tells me it's probably improper and ill-advised, but I'd still love to know if there are any methods for this.

Why would entering a new contractor or designer via combobox "Not In List" event be an interruption to data entry flow? That's what it's for - to facilitate data entry without interruption. No need to abort input of Project to go enter a new Designer/Contractor/Property then start over again with Project input.
